# Why won't browsers trust a self-signed SSL certificate from IIS?

Tags: iis, certificate, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I have an externally hosted IIS web server where I run my website. I would like to add a self-signed certificate to this website and trust it on my local client, to remove "Insecure Connection" from the browser.

What I have done so far is the following:

1. Created a self-signed certificate in IIS via the "Server Certificates -> Create self signed Certificate" path. The certificate is issued to the server name (e.g `ABCD01`)
2. Created a website with an HTTPS binding using the self-signed certificate.
3. Exported the self-signed certificate from IIS using the "Server Certificates -> Export" path. This resulted in a .pfx file
4. Imported the .pfx certificate file onto the local client via the "manage computer certificates -> Trusted Root certification authorities -> import" path
5. Added the server's host name (`ABCD01`) and IP address of the host to the hosts file: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

However, when I try to open the website in Firefox (using `https://ABCD01`), I still get the following error:

> Your connection is not secure.

Chrome does not work, either. What am I missing?

Comment: What browser you are using? BTW, you don't need to export the certificate in PFX, you need to export it in `.CER` format without private key.

Comment: I'm using Firefox or Chrome

Comment: I have written a very detailed walk-through on how to create self-signed certs for IIS on Windows. It should answer all your questions and give you ways to test and debug the results. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51261506/430742

Comment: Try this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59733055/10794140  in which i described how to trust a cert in detail. And it also works for firefox.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

1. IIS certificate generator creates self-signed certificates with SHA1 signature algorithm which is obsolete in modern browsers. You have to use different tools to create test certificates. For example, use PowerShell `New-SelfSignedCertificate` cmdlet where you can specify signature algorithm. Look at this post to get an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45284368/3997611

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate `
    -DnsName "ABCD01" `
    -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" `
    -FriendlyName "test dev cert" `
    -TextExtension "2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1" `
    -KeyUsage DigitalSignature,KeyEncipherment,DataEncipherment `
    -Provider "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" `
    -HashAlgorithm "SHA256"
```

2. IIS certificate generator cannot build certificate with SAN (Subject Alternative Names) certificate extension which is required in Google Chrome. You have to use different tools to create test certificates. Look at the example above for reference.
3. Google Chrome uses built-in Windows Certificate store to establish a trust, while FireFox uses its own certificate store. Therefore, after adding the certificate to Windows certificate store, you have to import your test certificate to FireFox manually.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! I changed the certificate to SHA256 as you explained. The problem with Firefox was exactly as you explained, the separate certificate store. As soon as it was imported it worked.

Comment: Update for anyone finding this answer in 2019: IIS certificate generator now uses the far more secure SHA256RSA algorithm. You can check the algorithm of your certificate by going to `Server Certificates -> Your certificate -> View -> Details`.

Comment: @Crypt32 how can I set the DnsName to be localhost? Thanks

Comment: @Adam IIS 10 indeed uses SHA256, but the certificates are missing `DigitalSignature` key usage, which is now required by Edge (and I assume other modern browsers).