# How to create and trust an SSL certificate using OpenSSL?

Tags: ssl, iis, openssl

How can I create valid certificate using OpenSSL for using HTTPS binding in IIS?

It must work in Firefox and all other browsers as well

I am using IIS 10. I want the HTTPS binding to work in all modern browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A certification authority has to be created to use *HTTPS* binding and hereby all our certificates will be signed from it. For that download a suitable version of OpenSSL from here: [Win32/Win64 OpenSSL Installer for Windows](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) And install it. Then, for fast and easier working a few script file can be made,

In the folder (in which the script is running) add a folder named `#`. All the certificate files will be stored there.

for making root certificate's create `RootCA.bat`,

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out #/RootCA.key 4096
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -sha256 -days 730 -key #/RootCA.key -out #/RootCA.crt -config rootca.csr
openssl pkcs12 -export -out #/RootCA.p12 -inkey #/RootCA.key -in #/RootCA.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out #/RootCA.pem -inkey #/RootCA.key -in #/RootCA.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out #/RootCA.pfx -inkey #/RootCA.key -in #/RootCA.crt
```

For `RootCA`'s details create `RootCa.csr`,

```
[req]
default_bits = 4096
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C=US
ST=New York
L=Rochester
O=Developer
OU=CodeSigner
CN=*.codesigning.in

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = *.codesigning.in
```

When you Run `RootCA.bat` it  will create a certificate using `RootCa.csr`'s details and Export a `.pem`, `.pfx` and `.p12` along with certificate file (a `RootCA.csr` and 'RootCA.key' is also created).

Now, for servers certificate create `server.bat`,

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out #/server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout #/server.key -config server.csr
openssl x509 -req -in #/server.csr -CA #/RootCA.crt -CAkey #/RootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out #/server.crt -days 365 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext
openssl pkcs12 -export -out #/server.p12 -inkey #/server.key -in #/server.crt -chain -CAfile #/RootCA.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out #/server.pem -inkey #/server.key -in #/server.crt -chain -CAfile #/RootCA.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out #/server.pfx -inkey #/server.key -in #/server.crt -chain -CAfile #/RootCA.crt
```

And for details create a `server.csr` file,

```
[req]
default_bits = 4096
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C=US
ST=New York
L=Rochester
O=Developer
OU=Test & Learn
CN=*.localhost.in

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = *.localhost.in
```

And, another file named `v3.ext` (I don't quite know about it),

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = *.localhost.in
```

Again When you Run `server.bat` it  will create a certificate using `server.csr`'s details and Export a `.pem`, `.pfx` and `.p12` along with certificate file (a `server.csr` and `server.key` is also created).

Note: You will have to modify the `server.csr` for your custom domains (default by, its gonna create for `dev.localhost.in` domain).

Warning: You Have to remember the passwords you enter. And You might modify the `RootCA.csr` and `RootCA.bat` as your need. (to increase expiration, modify deatails etc.)

Adding to Windows,

As I use Windows I only know about importing to Windows. To add in windows simply click on the `RootCA.p12` file and import it. Remember, you have to trust the `RootCA` in *Trusted Root Certification Authourity* And in *Intermediate Certification Authourity*.

All the browsers except for Firefox will trust the site.

You can check it using *mmc* in the run. And then snap-in certificates using `Ctrl` + `M`.

Adding to Firefox:

Because Firefox uses it own Certificate Managers and doesn't pay any heed to systems certificates. So, You will have to manually have to import the `RootCA.crt` for trust And all the inheriting certificates will be trusted. As Follows,
[image: Des]
[image: Des]

NOW, Import the certificate and simply add HTTPS binding with the certificate And Host the website using any server (even IIS etc).