# how to establish a non secure connection

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, connection

i have been building a website on WordPress; however, i have changed the URL to  instead of  by mistake.
i have not purchased a certificate yet.
now i can not have access to the dashboard from my browser, so i want to establish a non secure connection to reverse the URL back again.
i have tried disabling firewall, clearing cache and many other methods to avoid the certificate  like
**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors"** but can not avoid to establish non secure connection

Comment: You can change the URL in Wordpress without accessing the dashboard. See the answer to this question [How to disable HTTPS and redirect HTTPS to HTTP in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62315483/how-to-disable-https-and-redirect-https-to-http-in-wordpress/62317028#62317028)

Answer (score 0):

Just simply make a local certificate and you are good to go, You can use `xca` software or even `OpenSSl`,

I wrote a answer to do so using `OpenSSl` https://stackoverflow.com/a/59733055/10794140 just skim to certificate installation and trusting.

And, yes using `xca` is more simple with the good user interface, recommended to check out.