# Cannot set HTTP URI in redirect URI on Azure AD Web App

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I'm implementing a Power BI Embedding solution into third party application which uses the same Active Directory as Power BI. However the application has URL with HTTP and not HTTPS.

Now, for getting the authentication token for embedding, I've created Azure AD Web App and I want to add Redirect URI for that application, but it is not allowing me because it is HTTP.

What can be the solution to get authentication token for Azure AD for embedding?

Thank you.

Comment: `http` is no longer supported in Azure AD app (except `http://localhost`) at this moment. How about redirecting `https://yourapp` to `http://yourapp`?

Comment: Thank you @AllenWu - Do you mean redirecting third party app from Http://Appurl to Https://Appurl? It had issues with SSL Sync and certificates. Can I use Native App to get Auth Token for embedding Power BI report?

Comment: @MittalPatel did you find a solution for this (for http)?

Answer (score 2):

Apps that are registered for Microsoft identity platform has [Restrictions on redirect URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#restrictions-on-redirect-urls). The redirect URL for web apps and 
services must begin with the scheme **https**, and all redirect URL values must share a single DNS domain. http://localhost is also supported as a redirect URL.

You can create self signed certificates for https domain (for test purpose).If your app runs in Production Environment, it should be signed by a 
trusted certificate authority.Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate) to know more.

Refer this post for : [Trust a self signed cert from IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641473/trust-a-self-signed-cert-from-iis?noredirect=1&lq=1)